# Getting the unique values from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a small java console program, which inputs a CSV file with vehicle details into an ArrayList. One of the columns is the type of vehicle (Sedan, coupe, etc). I want to output the unique types of vehicles entered, but I'm not sure how to do this without over complicating it. Is there any easy way to get the unique values out of my list?
What is the easiest way for me to do this?

```
static List<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    textFileReader();
}

public static void textFileReader() {
    try {
                    
        File myObj = new File("~/Fleet.csv");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        String header = myReader.nextLine();

        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            String[] stringArrayVehicles = data.split(",");
            
            String vehicleID = stringArrayVehicles[0];
            String brand = stringArrayVehicles[1];
            String model = stringArrayVehicles[2];
            String type = stringArrayVehicles[3];
            String color = stringArrayVehicles[6];
            int yearOfManufacture = Integer.parseInt(stringArrayVehicles[4]);
            int seats = Integer.parseInt(stringArrayVehicles[5]);
            int rentPerDay = Integer.parseInt(stringArrayVehicles[7]);
            int insurancePerDay = Integer.parseInt(stringArrayVehicles[8]);
            int serviceFee = Integer.parseInt(stringArrayVehicles[9]);
            String discount = stringArrayVehicles[10];
            
            vehicle.add(new Vehicle(vehicleID, brand, model, type, color, yearOfManufacture, seats, rentPerDay, insurancePerDay, serviceFee, discount));                
                
      }
      myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be so put the vehicle names into a `Set` - depending on your requirements that could be a `HashSet`(unordered but fast), a `TreeSet` (ordered by natural order or via `Comparator`) or a `LinkedHashSet` (ordered by order of insertion). - If you need only use a list then you could try the following: 1) sort the list by vehicle type (if you want to keep the original list create a copy first), 2) iterate over the list and keep track of the last type you saw, 3) if the current and the last type are different as per `equals()`, print the current one.

Comment: Simple. Just keep the list of unique vehicle types in another csv file OR into the same csv file but at the first/last line of your csv file. Whenever your program starts, load the full list of unique vehicles and store into a HashSet/HashMap. When the user attempts to add a new entry, add the vehicle type input by user in the HashSet/HashMap. If the same vehicle already exist, it won't be added. At the end of the program write all the vehicle type into the csv file.

Comment: How has your issue not been addressed by the very many similar Questions and Answers?

Comment: Since you are only interested in a list of unique type of vehicles such as sedan, coup, and so on, use a set of string and add stringArrayVehicles[3] to the set.  Then print the set and it should shows all the unique vehicle types.